# How is margin-bottom: auto calculated?

Tags: html, css, margin

I noticed that there was a lot of empty space under my `#thing` div. My `#thing` margin was set to `margin: 100px auto;`, so I changed it to `margin: 100px auto 0px auto;`, and the empty space went away. Why would a `margin-bottom` set to `auto` create a bunch of empty space? It wasn't just trying to fill the visible screen, because my div extended beyond the height of my screen; I had to scroll down to see the empty space.

Comment: `100px auto` mean margin top and bottom is set to 100px and left/right is set to auto

Comment: @anpsmn Ohhhhh well that explains it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shorthand `margin: 100px auto;` expands to `margin: 100px auto 100px auto;` which means:

```
margin-top: 100px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 100px;
margin-left: auto;
```

So you weren't seeing extra space because of `margin-bottom: auto;`. In fact, the value `auto` has no meaning when assigned to `margin-top` or `margin-bottom`.

***Edit:*** See @web-tiki's comment below about a use-case for `auto` with `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.

For reference, the shorthand options for `margin` are:

```
margin: [top] [right] [bottom] [left];
margin: [top] [right/left] [bottom];
margin: [top/bottom] [left/right];
```

Comment: `auto` does have a "meaning" when assigned to top and bottom margins. It can be very usefull to [verticaly center an element in a block](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/3jsosb4x/1/) or [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/3jsosb4x/2/).

Comment: @web-tiki: Only when the element is absolutely positioned and [certain conditions](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height) are [met](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-replaced-height).

Comment: Still, that's a nice trick! I've updated my answer to point to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is a certain amount of implicit `padding` and `margin` given to block-level elements, including `html` and `body`. If you've ever encountered a `reset.css`, then you know you're not the only one who find this frustrating.

Use Chrome Developer Tools' "Box Model" tool in the righthand bar to see these figures visualized (right-click the element, "Inspect element", "Computed").